# I have ng-click inside ng-repeat inside ul and 2 buttons are getting clicked

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have `ng-click` inside 2 of my tags. When I click the `X` button the Done button is getting clicked as well. This only happens when there is only one object in the collection that is being repeated.

```html
<ul class="chat-options">

  <li ng-repeat="possibleValue in property.PossibleValues track by $index"
      ng-init="propertyValueIndexIndex = $index"
      ng-mouseover="EnablePropertyValueEditing(possibleValue)"
      style="display: inline-block; margin-left: 20px; margin-right: 10px; margin-bottom: 2px; height: 26px;">

    <div>
      <label class="chat-option-name">
        {{possibleValue.value}}
      </label>

      <!--delete a property value-->
      <button class="chat-option chat-option-remove"
              ng-disabled="!possibleValue.edit"
              ng-click="RemovePropertyValue(property, possibleValue, this)">
        X
      </button>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li style="display: inline-block; margin-right: 10px; margin-bottom: 2px; height: 26px;">
    <button class="chat-option-name {{property.Name.replace(' ','_')}}-done" ng-click="DisablePropertyEditing(property)">Done</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you provide some code, so we can understand the problem.

Comment: When you say the "Done button is getting clicked" do you mean `DisablePropertyEditing` is being called?